# Integrating New OAuth Consent Scopes into a Google Application

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

We currently use a set of OAuth Consent scopes in our production application, all of which have been verified with Google as part of our app:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Now, we're looking to expand our application by integrating new restricted scopes related to Gmail:

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata

To ensure a seamless integration and compliance with Google's standards, we want to make sure we follow the correct procedures and adhere to all the necessary standards when adding these new scopes to our application.

Could anyone provide guidance on the required steps and any standards that must be followed in this process (like to send application for reverification)? Can our current app out of verification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75854967/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56086559/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76356686/1427878

Answer (score 0):

Just add them over in the consent screen then submit your app for verification again. You will have to submit a new YouTube video like you did for the drive scope.

You will also have to go though a new security assessment for the gmail scope.

Your current app will continue to work as long as you dont try to use the new scopes if you do then the users will get the unverified apps screen for the new scopes.  They will not get it for the scope you have already verfied.